# using differents colors for the same button component in styles.ts

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, react-native

I'm very struck into some idea. I've made the component `SocialButton.tsx` and I use him for "Login with Google/Facebook" buttons on mobile apps. However, for me I can just style him with one single color defined in the `styles.ts` and I would like to put different colors because, as everyone knows, the Facebook color button on mobile apps usually is blue, and for Google is white, so I can't use one of these colors for both buttons. Anyone got something on mind that could solve my struggle?

This is the `SocialButton.tsx`:

```
import React from 'react'
import { Fontisto } from "@expo/vector-icons";
import { RectButtonProps } from 'react-native-gesture-handler'
import { IconFacebook, Title, Button } from './styles'

interface Props extends RectButtonProps {
    title?: string
    iconName:React.ComponentProps<typeof Fontisto> ['name']
}

import PngGoogle from '../../assets/google.png'
const ButtonSocial: React.FC<Props> = ({title, iconName, ...rest}) => {
  return (
    <Button {...rest}>
        <IconFacebook name={iconName}/>
        <Title>{title}</Title>
    </Button>
  )
}

export {ButtonSocial}
```

The `styles.ts`, where I want to do the color thing:

```
import styled from "styled-components/native";
import { Fontisto } from "@expo/vector-icons";
import { RectButton } from "react-native-gesture-handler";
import {RFValue} from 'react-native-responsive-fontsize'

export const Button = styled(RectButton)`
    width: ${RFValue(130)}px;
    height: ${RFValue(60)}px;
    border-radius: ${RFValue(5)}px;
    margin-left: ${RFValue(10)}px;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: row;
    margin-bottom: 16px;
    background-color: ${({theme}) => theme.COLORS.BLUE};
`;

export const IconFacebook = styled(Fontisto)`
    font-size: ${RFValue(25)}px;
    color: ${({theme}) => theme.COLORS.WHITE_100};

`

export const Title = styled.Text `
    font-size: ${RFValue(15)}px;
    margin-left: ${RFValue(10)}px;
    color: ${({theme}) => theme.COLORS.WHITE_100};
    font-family: ${({theme}) => theme.FONTS.POPPINSLIGHT};
`
```

And here is `Login.tsx` where the `ButtonSocial` appears, but with the same color for both buttons:

```
import React from 'react'
import { SafeAreaView } from 'react-native'
import { 
    Container,
    ContentHeader,
    ContentBody,
    ContentFooter,
    Title,
    Description,
    ViewButton, 
} from './styles'

import { ButtonSocialGoogle } from '../../components/ButtonSocialGoogle/ButtonSocialGoogle'

import { ButtonSocial } from '../../components/ButtonSocial/ButtonSocial'

const Login: React.FC = () => {
  return (
    <SafeAreaView>
        <Container>
            <ContentHeader>
                <Title>Welcome{"\n"} to Wallet App</Title>
                <Description>Sign up with:</Description>
                <ViewButton>
                    <ButtonSocial iconName="google"/>
                    <ButtonSocial iconName="facebook"/>

                </ViewButton>
            </ContentHeader>
            <ContentBody></ContentBody>
            <ContentFooter></ContentFooter>
        </Container>
    </SafeAreaView>
  )
}

export {Login}
```

I had imported the `SocialButtonGoogle` which is a specific button for Goggle but he's not in the code anymore because I want to use only the `SocialButton` with the respective color for Google and Facebook buttons. Maybe It's a dumb question, but it is what it is. Also I hope my question is clear enough.